# Am I billed multiple times when reading items within the same query set with Firebase?

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm a bit confused on how billing works with Firebase Firestore.

If I request all the user's `projects` as follows and I get back 8 projects

`db.collection("projects").where("uid", "==", auth.currentUser.uid);`

and then a few minutes later I do the following:

`db.collection("projects").doc("Project123")` where `Project123` was in the first query set, do I incur billing for another read?
Or is the data pulled from some sort of cache, assuming the data never changed between reads?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should first read and understand the [documentation for Firestore persistence](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/enable-offline).  The general rule is that if a read could be satisfied by local persistence without requiring an update from the server, there is no charge for a read.  But you need to understand ahead of time if you have persistence enabled.  At the time of this writing, persistence is by default for mobile apps on Android and iOS.  It is not for web.  There is no persistence for for server SDKs.